# What are the differences between the 32-bit and 64-bit installers of Flash Player?

Tags: firefox, 64-bit, browser, flash, opera

**What are the differences between the [32-bit and 64-bit installers of Flash Player](http://www.filehippo.com/download_flashplayer/)? Does the 64-bit installer also contain the 32-bit plugin?**

I'm asking as I've noticed that installing the 64-bit version of Flash, will also update the 32-bit version. I downloaded and installed the current latest version of the [64-bit non-IE version of Flash](http://www.filehippo.com/download_flashplayer_firefox_64/). I checked the [Flash version check page](http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/) and the `about:plugins` page on my installation of the browsers, [Opera (64-bit)](http://www.opera.com/browser/download/) and Firefox (32-bit) in my computer, and the versions of Flash for both have been upgraded to the current latest version.

In Opera (which is the 64-bit version), I checked that I am using the 64-bit (native) version of Flash, not the 32-bit version of the plugin. I am using Windows 7, 64-bit.

I also remember one instance where I installed the 32-bit non-IE version of Flash, and upon checking the `about:plugins` page, the 64-bit Flash plugin used by my 64-bit Opera got updated too (along with the 32-bit Firefox plugin). So, this makes me wonder if there are differences between the 32-bit and 64-bit installers at all.

Note: Although my experience and the info I am personally looking for only covers the non-IE, Windows versions of the Flash installer, I also would like to ask for info on the differences between the 32-bit and 64-bit version of the IE Flash installers, and the non-Windows Flash installers, to [make this question relevant to others](https://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(I found this information as I was researching stuff to add to my question, so I answered this question myself.)*

Starting from Flash Player version 11.3, there is now one 'universal installer' of Flash for Windows (combining the 32-bit and 64-bit versions) - one for the IE browser and another one for non-IE browsers.  If you have the 64-bit version of Windows, the Flash 'universal installer' will install both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Flash.

(I.e. starting from Flash Player v11.3, the 32-bit and 64-bit installers for the same browser types are the same.)

Sources:

- [Post by an Adobe Employee in this Adobe forums thread - Why does the site keep downloading the 32bit version of flash player when I'm running a 64bit system](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4589997#4589997)
- [Flash player help page - You are having problems installing Flash Player on 64-bit Internet Explorer on Windows 7](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/flash-player-64-bit-operating.html)