# Problems with Adobe Flash

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, internet-explorer, flash, opera

I'm running Windows 7, 64-Bit on a Core-i5 HP Notebook. For approximately the last 3 months, I've had major problems with Adobe Flash. Flash has been uninstalled and installed again multiple times. No changes.

Here is what happens in different browsers: (All browsers are in the latest version as of this post)

- Firefox: Doesn't work at all. This bothers me most, since FF is my favorite browser; I'm using a lot of Plugins. Have tried to de-activate all Plugins, but no change.
- IE and Chrome: Works, but most pages with Flash are stuck during page load for ~30 seconds. After that, everything is fine.
- Opera: No problems, everything working as it should.

Strange, eh?  Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using the latest version of Flash for each browser. See the [Flash version checker webpage](http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/) in each browser, and check if you are using the latest version for that browser. If not, update your copy of Flash for that browser: http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer.

Verify if the latest version of Flash is installed properly per browser. In Firefox and Chrome, type `about:plugins`. For IE, go to the Tools Button (gear icon) - Manage Add-ons ([detailed instructions here](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows7/How-to-manage-add-ons-in-Internet-Explorer-9#)). This should list all installed plug-ins and their versions. You can also recheck at the [Flash version checker webpage](http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/).

Note that:

IE uses different Flash plugins (and has a different installer) than Firefox and Opera (there's an IE version and a non-IE version of the Flash installer).

The Google Chrome browser (32-bit) includes Adobe Flash Player built-in. Chrome automatically updates when new versions of Flash Player are available... Select About Google Chrome under the Tools menu to verify that your Chrome browser is up-to-date. (The wrench icon near the Chrome address bar indicates the Tools menu.)  It can take some time before updates roll out to all Chrome users. [(Source)](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/flash-player-google-chrome.html).

[Opera has a 64-bit version](http://www.opera.com/browser/download/), and that version can use the 64-bit Flash plugin. Also, starting from Flash Player v11.3, [the 32-bit and 64-bit installers for the same browser types are the same](https://superuser.com/q/462246/10259). This means that if you have a 64-bit version of Windows, the Flash 'universal installer' will install both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Flash for that installer's browser type.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately. it still doesn't work. I have the latest version of flash in Firefox. I also tried to set off the sandbox mode (like mentioned in the other answer here), but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

A recent update to Flash plugin for Firefox has introduced sandboxing where the Flash process is separate from Firefox's plugin container for extra security. This has caused some issues where the Flash plugin is not working properly, however.

Once you have ensured that you are using the latest version of Firefox (Firefox button -> Help -> About Firefox) and the latest version of Flash ([check here](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/)), then follow these instructions to disable the sandboxing to see if this will make the plugin work properly:

1. Find the mms.cfg file:

   - Windows 32-bit users: `C:\windows\system32\macromed\flash`
   - Windows 64-bit users: `C:\windows\syswow64\macromed\flash`
2. Move (drag) the mms.cfg file to your Desktop.
3. Edit the mms.cfg file using Notepad and add this line to the end of it: `ProtectedMode=0`.
4. Move the mms.cfg file back to where it was.
5. Restart your computer and try again.

If this does not solve your issues, then re-enable protected mode by removing the line you added.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I tried both steps exactly as you wrote, but it doesn't help. I have the latest version, and I set Protected=0. But still, Flash and youtube do not work in Firefox.